# Generic type 'ElementRef<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, angular6, package.json

im encountering the following error when using ElementRef:

> Generic type 'ElementRef' requires 2 type argument(s)

The only suggestion I found is to update my angular version, which I did (using the lastest one). I updated every single package. Sadly nothing changed. The code:

**component**

```
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewInit,OnDestroy,ViewChild,ChangeDetectorRef,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild('cardInfo') cardInfo: ElementRef;
}
```

The error is thrown by ElementRef

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "demo-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.4",
    "angular-jsvat": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i tried both ElementRef<HTMLElement> and ElementRef<HTMLElement,any>. None of them work

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, that's why I don't know what else to do :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I wasted a couple of hours on this but finally found the solution. It has something to do with typescript. I updated typescript from 2.7.2 to 2.9.2 (global and local) and the error is not showing anymore. I think the solutions posted in older questions about this issue are really misleading.